# Isomorphism from a set of $n\times n$ matrices with trace $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I am wondering how I would find an isomorphism from a set of matrices of dimension $n\times n$ with a specific value for the trace. For simplicity, let us say the trace must be equal to $1$, although this could be generalized to any value of $x$.

I understand that this places a restriction on the matrix, such that a matrix $A \in M_{n,n}$ would need to look like the following:
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & 1 - \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_{ii} \right)
\end{bmatrix}

As far as I can tell, I then have $n^2-n$ free elements off of the diagonal, and $n-1$ free elements on the diagonal. I believe that I could then create an isomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^{n^2-1}$.

I think my challenge here is that $M_{n,n}$ is not a vector space. I am then struggling with the idea of dimensionality. Does $M_{n,n}$ simply have dimension $n^2-1$?

Comment: Set of matrices with trace 1 doesn't form a vector space, so what kind of isomorphism are you interested in ? you should define that properly

Comment: I am looking for a vector space that this set is isomorphic to. Is that the right way of defining what type of isomorphism I am looking for?

Comment: If the given set if not a vector space then you cannot have an isomorphism with a vector space, by definition to establish isomorphism you need both sets to be vector spaces, may be if you could share more about what structure exactly do you want on this set because a vector space structure with usual matrix addition is not possible

Answer (score 1):

If $x\neq0$, then the set of matrices $T_x=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})\mid\operatorname{tr}(A)=x\}$ is not a subspace but the formula $T_x=A+T_0$ for some matrix $A$ with trace $x$ is satisfied. Hence, we can assume that $\dim T_x=\dim T_0=n^2-1$, since we know that $T_0$ is a subspace in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.
In this case, I don't think it makes sense to talk about isomorphism $T_x$ and $T_0$.
In any case it is necessary to understand what you want from this isomorphism. What structure should it preserve?

Comment: I am not entirely sure. Based off my reading on the topic, I am looking for a linear isomorphism. I would like the transformation to preserve linearity, and have the transformation be bijective, but my understand this is what an isomorphism does by definition. Is there somewhere I can read more about how different isomorphisms preserve different elements of structure that you recommend?

Comment: Hmm, you mean a linear mapping defined on $T_x$. If $x\neq0$, then for $A,B\in T_x$ we have $A+B\not\not\in T_x$. As you can see it is not very clear what is a linear mapping defined on $T_x$. Maybe tell us about the source of your questions.

Comment: Here's something that might help you. If 
$\sum\alpha_i=1$ and $A_i\in T_x$, then $\sum\alpha_i A_i\in T_x$. Is that good enough for you?  Then the "linearity" of $f$ can mean that $f$ preserves such linear combinations.